# Subsetting data by time frame window for each row in a data frame after using group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have time-series data with three columns: a value column, a group_var column (used for grouping), and a date column. For each row in the data frame, I'd like to get the mean of that row's group after further subsetting by a specific timeframe. Here's an example of the code for subsetting:

```
df$value[df$date >= (current_row$date - 545) & df$date <= (current_row$date - 365)]
```

After I get this subset I can easily apply mean(), but where I'm stuck on is how I can get this code to work with something like this:

```
df %>%
    group_by(group_var) %>%
      mutate(subset_mean = mean(df$value[df$date >= (current_row$date - 545) & df$date <= (current_row$date - 365)])
)
```

The issues I see is that I don't think I can use 'df' inside the mutate() line after I group the original 'df'. Also I'm not sure how I can create 'current_row' variable for referencing the current row to calculate the data subset.

Edit:
Added example data and reproducible code

```
library(dplyr)
date <- c("2016-02-03", "2016-06-14", "2016-03-15", "2017-04-16","2016-01-27", "2016-01-13", "2017-04-24", "2017-06-15")
date <- date %>% as.Date(format = "%Y-%m-%d")
val <- c(10, 20, 50, 70, 30, 44, 67, 42)
group_var <- c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B")

df <- data.frame(date, val, group_var)
 
df %>% 
  group_by(group_var)
```

Comment: Added example data/inputs

Comment: To confirm, are you looking for the mean across the window that is between 545 to 365 days prior?

Comment: Yeah that is the time-frame that I want to subset the data for. 545 to 365 days prior to each row's own date. There might be some rows where their subset will have no rows in that case the subset_mean returned should be NA

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @rstats23. Please consider upvoting the solutions that work for you. For the solution that you find most appealing, please also mark that solution as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `slider::slide_index_dbl` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>%
  arrange(group_var, date) %>%   # slider 0.1.5 requires the window variable to be ascending
  mutate(subset_mean = slider::slide_index_dbl(
    val, date, mean, .before = 545, .after = -365   
    # negative ".after" means the window ends before the current date
  )) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

With the updated data, I get

```
#date <- c("2016-02-03", "2016-06-14", "2016-03-15", "2017-04-16","2016-01-27", "2016-01-13", "2017-04-24", "2017-06-15")


# A tibble: 8 x 4
  date         val group_var subset_mean
  <date>     <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1 2016-01-13    44 A               NaN  
2 2016-02-03    10 A               NaN  
3 2017-04-16    70 A                27  
4 2017-04-24    67 A                27  
5 2016-01-27    30 B               NaN  
6 2016-03-15    50 B               NaN  
7 2016-06-14    20 B               NaN  
8 2017-06-15    42 B                33.3
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: If I added in another column containing boolean values and only wanted to calculate subset_mean for rows where the boolean value was TRUE, how would that work? I've added the code I've tried with ifelse() and case_when() into the original post

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This can be done with a self join using sql:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.date, a.val, a.group_var, avg(b.val) as mean
  from df a
  left join df b on a.group_var = b.group_var and
    b.date between a.date - 595 and a.date - 365
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
        date val group_var     mean
1 2016-02-03  10         A       NA
2 2016-06-14  20         B       NA
3 2016-03-15  50         B       NA
4 2017-04-16  70         A 27.00000
5 2016-01-27  30         B       NA
6 2016-01-13  44         A       NA
7 2017-04-24  67         A 27.00000
8 2017-06-15  42         B 33.33333
```

**2)** or we can use SQL window functions:

```
sqldf("select date, val, group_var,
  avg(val) over (partition by group_var 
                 order by date 
                 range between 595 preceding and 365 preceding) as mean
  from df"
)
```

giving:

```
        date val group_var     mean
1 2016-01-13  44         A       NA
2 2016-02-03  10         A       NA
3 2017-04-16  70         A 27.00000
4 2017-04-24  67         A 27.00000
5 2016-01-27  30         B       NA
6 2016-03-15  50         B       NA
7 2016-06-14  20         B       NA
8 2017-06-15  42         B 33.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

Lubridate provides a very elegant solution...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = tibble(
  value = runif(100,1,100),
  group = rep(1:4,25),
  dt = as.Date(round(runif(100,1000,2000)), origin = "1970-01-01")
)

first_year <- interval(ymd("1972-01-01"), ymd("1972-12-31"))
sec_year <- interval(ymd("1973-01-01"), ymd("1973-12-31"))
furhter <- interval(ymd("1974-01-01"), ymd("1975-12-31"))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    range = case_when(
      dt %within% first_year ~"1972",
      dt %within% sec_year ~"1973",
      TRUE ~"1974-1975"
    )
  )

mean_by_group_interval <- df %>% 
  group_by(
    group,
    range
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean = mean(value)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that utilizes the `dplyr` package.

```r
library(dplyr)

date <- c("2016-02-03", "2016-06-14", "2016-03-15", "2017-04-16","2016-01-27", "2016-01-13", "2017-04-24", "2017-06-15")
date <- date %>% as.Date(format = "%Y-%m-%d")
val <- c(10, 20, 50, 70, 30, 44, 67, 42)
group_var <- c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B")

df <- data.frame(date, val, group_var)


df %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>%
  arrange(group_var, date) %>% 
  mutate(
    # Determine if the current date - the first date of each group is between 365 and 595 days.
    match = between(date - first(date), 365, 595),
    # Count the number of dates that are not within the range described above to be used in calculating the mean.
    count_false = sum(match == FALSE),
    # Calculate the cumulative sum for rows in each group that are not within the range described above.
    sum_match_false = ifelse(match == FALSE, cumsum(val), NA),
    # Calculate the mean.
    mean_match_true = ifelse(match == TRUE, max(sum_match_false, na.rm = TRUE) / count_false, NA)
  ) %>% 
  # Return only these variables.
  select(date, val, group_var, mean_match_true)


#>   date         val group_var mean_match_true
#>   <date>     <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1 2016-01-13    44 A                    NA  
#> 2 2016-02-03    10 A                    NA  
#> 3 2017-04-16    70 A                    27  
#> 4 2017-04-24    67 A                    27  
#> 5 2016-01-27    30 B                    NA  
#> 6 2016-03-15    50 B                    NA  
#> 7 2016-06-14    20 B                    NA  
#> 8 2017-06-15    42 B                    33.3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>